I want to display a list in react native so which one is better approach
<ScrollView>
<FlatList>
</FlatList>
</ScrollView>

or
<ScrollView>
<VirtualizedList>
</VirtualizedList>
</ScrollView>


error is "VirtualizedLists should never be nested" error
1st one throws error and i've to show data using map but that is not feasible so which one is better?
I tried map to show data but it is not good with large number of data

I would suggest the first option.
Given that you have a DATA array, you can use Flatlist like this:
<FlatList
    data={DATA}
    renderItem={({item}) => <Item title={item.title} />}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
  />

but, I would also consider using something like FlashList:
https://shopify.github.io/flash-list/
